# Case en consulta sql

Tags: sql, condiciones

Estoy haciendo una consulta en sqlsrv 2000, a varias tablas donde hay dos campos `estado` y `estado2` (que hacen lo mismo, no se por que los hicieron así) que guardan `0` y `1`.

Actualmente tengo un case en esa parte de la consulta para que cuando estado sea igual 0, entonces `estado='NO'`, y si es 1 entonces `estado='SI'`. pERO SOLO PREGUNTO POR EL CAMPO `estado`, y necesito preguntar si al menos uno de los dos tiene valor 1 o 0 sin agregar una nueva columna a la consulta.

esta es la parte de la consulta que tengo:

```
CASE a.estado
    WHEN 1 THEN 'SI'
    WHEN 0 THEN 'NO'
END AS Estado
```

Ojala me hayan entendido.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar el `or` sin problemas:

```
CASE 
    WHEN a.estado = 1 or a.estado2 = 1 THEN 'SI' 
    ELSE 'NO' 
END AS Estado
```

Comment: gracias,funciona

Comment: Hola @daniel te recomiendo que te leas el tour y específicamente http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma para solucionar el Query es usando la función; **if** de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT IF(a.estado = 1, IF(a.estado2 = 1, 'SI','NO'),'NO') AS estado FROM tu_tabla
```

Con este query te deberá imprimir **SI** ó **NO** según sea el caso.

---

**Edición por Comentario**

Tomando en cuenta el comentario del colega [Miquel Coll](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/14701/case-en-consulta-sql/14716?noredirect=1#comment24351_14716), voy a simplificar el query, quedando de esta forma:

```
SELECT IF(estado = 1 OR estado2 = 1, 'SI','NO') AS estado FROM tu_tabla
```

Comment: Creo que puedes resumir lo que comentas `SELECT IF(a.estado = 1 OR a.estado2 = 1, 'SI','NO') AS estado FROM tu_tabla`

Comment: No lo he probado nunca así, pero me parece una muy buena idea, es mas voy a editar la respuesta y proponer lo que comentas. Gracias.

Comment: +1 por añadir la segunda opción ( y ser una respuesta correcta). Des de mi punto de vista y dada la simplicidad de la situación preferiría un case pero a veces es mejor utilizar un IF cuándo quieres concatenar condiciones.