# Ayuda con CASE en Consulta SQL

Tags: sql-server, condiciones

Primero voy a aclarar un punto se que esta pregunta es similar a la ya formulada anteriormente, entrando al siguiente enlace se puede ver:

[Case en consulta sql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/14701/case-en-consulta-sql)

Pero dado que esa pregunta no pudo resolver mi duda, luego de por supuesto ya haberla revisado bien, es por eso que voy a formular la siguiente pregunta.

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado el cual, al momento de ejecutarlo me arroja una serie de datos al introducir un rango de tiempo, día, mes y año. Y entre esos datos hay un campo estado, el cual me lo muestra con números, y mi idea es que me lo muestre escrito en palabras. Les dejo el código del procedimiento:

```
USE [PRUEBA_TRACK]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[OBTIENE_INFORME_GESTION]    
Script Date: 03/20/2018 11:29:46 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[OBTIENE_INFORME_GESTION]
@FDESDE VARCHAR(10),
@FHASTA VARCHAR(10)

AS

SELECT E.ID_ENVIO,CL.CLIENTE, E.TIPO, E.MODO, E.VOLUMEN, E.PESO, E.ALTO, 
E.LARGO, E.CONTENIDO, E.OBSERVACIONES, E.ESTADO, 

E.COD_INTERNO, E.NOMBRE_1, E.EMPRESA_1, E.NOMBRE_2,  S.SUCURSAL,
S.DIRECCION, C.COMUNA, E.REGION_2, 

E.ADMISION, E.FECHA_ADM, E.DESPACHO, T.vc1Valor


FROM SOLICITUD AS SC, CLIENTE AS CL, ENVIO AS E, TABLAS AS T, 
SUCURSALES AS S, COMUNA AS C


WHERE
E.ID_ENVIO = SC.ENVIO AND
E.ID_CLIENTE = CL.COD_CLIENTE AND 

E.REGION_2 = T.codigo AND T.codTabla = 12 AND

E.LOCALIDAD_2 = S.ID_SUCURSAL AND E.ID_CLIENTE = S.ID_CLIENTE AND 
E.COMUNA_2 = C.ID_COMUNA AND 

E.FECHA_ADM >= @FDESDE AND E.FECHA_ADM <= @FHASTA

ORDER BY CLIENTE
```

Luego a ese procedimiento almacenado le agregué el siguiente CASE:

```
CASE WHEN E.ESTADO = 1 THEN 'INGRESADO'
WHEN E.ESTADO = 2 THEN 'EN TRANSITO'
WHEN E.ESTADO = 3 THEN 'ENTREGADO'
WHEN E.ESTADO = 4 THEN 'OBJETADO DEFINITIVO'
WHEN E.ESTADO = 5 THEN 'OBJETADO NO DEFINITIVO'
WHEN E.ESTADO = 6 THEN 'ENTREGADO REMITENTE'
ELSE 'CODIGO GENERADO'
END
```

Pero claramente eso me agrega una columna demás, aunque los datos que muestra están bien, es solo que mi duda es, a modo de ejemplo:

¿Qué debo hacer para que cuando el valor del campo ESTADO es 1 me muestra 1, me muestre INGRESADO y no 1?

Eso a modo de ejemplo y claro si su valor es 2 mostrará EN TRANSITO y si su valor es 3 debe mostrar ENTREGADO y así sucesivamente; además, ¿Qué debo hacer para que además no se me agregue una nueva columna?

Espero que se haya entendido, gracias.

Comment: Si ya estás mostrando la columna `E.ESTADO`, simplemente reemplazala por la sentencia  `CASE` que has creado y si quieres nombra esta columna como `AS 'ESTADO'`, para mantener el mismo nombre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es bastante facil y hay varias opciones. Vamos con la primera usando tu consulta y tu case

```
USE [PRUEBA_TRACK]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[OBTIENE_INFORME_GESTION]    
Script Date: 03/20/2018 11:29:46 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[OBTIENE_INFORME_GESTION]
@FDESDE VARCHAR(10),
@FHASTA VARCHAR(10)

AS

SELECT E.ID_ENVIO,CL.CLIENTE, E.TIPO, E.MODO, E.VOLUMEN, E.PESO, E.ALTO, 
E.LARGO, E.CONTENIDO, E.OBSERVACIONES,
CASE WHEN E.ESTADO = 1 THEN 'INGRESADO'
WHEN E.ESTADO = 2 THEN 'EN TRANSITO'
WHEN E.ESTADO = 3 THEN 'ENTREGADO'
WHEN E.ESTADO = 4 THEN 'OBJETADO DEFINITIVO'
WHEN E.ESTADO = 5 THEN 'OBJETADO NO DEFINITIVO'
WHEN E.ESTADO = 6 THEN 'ENTREGADO REMITENTE'
ELSE 'CODIGO GENERADO'
END as Estado, 

E.COD_INTERNO, E.NOMBRE_1, E.EMPRESA_1, E.NOMBRE_2,  S.SUCURSAL,
S.DIRECCION, C.COMUNA, E.REGION_2, 

E.ADMISION, E.FECHA_ADM, E.DESPACHO, T.vc1Valor


FROM SOLICITUD AS SC, CLIENTE AS CL, ENVIO AS E, TABLAS AS T, 
SUCURSALES AS S, COMUNA AS C


WHERE
E.ID_ENVIO = SC.ENVIO AND
E.ID_CLIENTE = CL.COD_CLIENTE AND 

E.REGION_2 = T.codigo AND T.codTabla = 12 AND

E.LOCALIDAD_2 = S.ID_SUCURSAL AND E.ID_CLIENTE = S.ID_CLIENTE AND 
E.COMUNA_2 = C.ID_COMUNA AND 

E.FECHA_ADM >= @FDESDE AND E.FECHA_ADM <= @FHASTA

ORDER BY CLIENTE
```

La otra forma seria hacer una tabla de estados y hacer el JOIN para que si el dia de mañana tenes que agregar un estado no tengas que modificar el codigo, solo agregar un registro a la tabla estados

Comment: Disculpa pero no te entendí muy bien, me puedes aclarar tu idea por favor, gracias

Comment: La primera o la segunda?

Comment: La primera, pero la aplique en mi procedimiento almacenado y me funciono, luego entendí a que te referías, gracias